# How to create event view in react-big-calender

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar, react-calendar, event-calendar

I want to create a custom event **view** in react-big-calender. I go through the documentation. It's working fine. but still, the **labels** are visible in the slot

```
  const CustomEventComponent = ({ event }: any) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Text className='color-ffffff'>Hello</Text>
      </div>
    );
  };

<Calendar
  toolbar={false}
  localizer={localizer}
  events={myEventsList}
  startAccessor='start'
  endAccessor='end'
  showAllEvents={true}
  defaultView={Views.DAY}
  components={{
    event: CustomEventComponent,
  }}
/>;
```

I had tried many examples but failed to **remove** the label. I don't know where I'm making a mistake. I have attached the image.
[image: Custom View with Label]
Can anyone guide me on how to **create a custom view** for an event?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, within a TimeGrid view the label (a div with a class of `rbc-event-label` is always there, with a time formatted by `eventTimeRangeStartFormat`, `eventTimeRangeFormat`, or `eventTimeRangeEndFormat`, depending on it's span.

You could override the `rbc-event-label` class, setting it to `display:none`, but I would be careful with that as it will take out screen reader access to the element as well.